# Ansible: Changing permissions of files inside a directory in .yml file

Tags: ansible

Suppose there's a directory /dir/tools.
tools contains a bunch of scripts, say, a.sh, b.sh, c.sh.

I need to set the permissions of a.sh, b.sh, and c.sh to 0775.

I've currently done it in the following manner:

```
- name: Fix 'support_tools' permissions
  file: path={{ item }} owner=abc group=abc mode=0775 
  with_items:
    - /dir/tools/a.sh
    - /dir/tools/b.sh
    - /dir/tools/c.sh
```

Btw, 'file: path=/dir/tools owner=abc group=abc mode=0775' sets the permission of tools directory but not of the files inside it.

Is there a better way of achieving this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `state=directory` to the second attempt?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
- name: Fix 'support_tools' permissions
  file: path=/dir/tools owner=abc group=abc mode=0775 state=directory recurse=yes
```

Comment: Another question: In case there are other directories besides a.sh, b.sh, and c.sh, and I don't want their permissions changed, how can they be excluded?

Comment: @Aarvi unfortunately it is all or nothing.

Answer (score 7):

This is a another way to do it, using ansible modules without "shell" or "command"

```
- name: lookup files with a certain pattern
  find:
    paths: /dir/tools/
    file_type: file
    patterns: "*.sh"
  register: filelist

- name: change permissions
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: file
    owner: abc
    group: abc
    mode: "0775"
  with_items: "{{ filelist.files }}"
```

Comment: i see, those what a one line shell command will achieve in less than 30 chars
is when performed in an Ansible conformant fashion expanding to some 20 lines of code.

Comment: @AlexanderStohr some people (like me) prefer to use Ansible in a declarative manner rather than an imperative one. Ansible isn't a programming language, so I don't treat it like one. Sometimes being verbose is better than being clever - especially if you're treating your Ansible YAML as documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Try it with below lines with "with_items" and -maxdepth 5

```
 vars:
    your_path: "/home/username/support_tools"
  tasks:
    - name: Fix 'support_tools' permissions
      command: "{{ item }}"
      with_items:
        - find {{ your_path }} -maxdepth 5 -type d ! -perm 0755 -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
        - find {{ your_path }} -maxdepth 5 -type f ! -perm 0644 -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip specifying group as well. Then check your yml file by running it with the --check parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
- name: Fix 'support_tools' permissions
   shell: 'chmod a+x /dir/tools/*'
```